# How to find the date a login password was last changed in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sybase

I'm porting stored procedures from Sybase 15 to SQL Server 2008.

In Sybase this statement calcs an expiration date by adding a number of days to syslogins.pwdate (Date the password was last changed) and works fine:

```
SELECT @l_pwd_date = dateadd( day, @l_pwd_max_expire, pwdate)
FROM master.dbo.syslogins
WHERE name = @v_user
```

...but throws this error when trying to compile it in SQL Server 2008:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 Invalid column name 'pwdate'.

`syslogins` in SQL Server 2008 no longer includes that column pwdate.

Does anyone know where could I find equivalent column in SQL Server 2008 or a workaround to find the date a login password was last changed?

Comment: FYI, syslogins is deprecated to sys.server_principals whic still doesn't have it. Nor sys.sql_logins

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the PasswordLastSetTime option of the [LOGINPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx).

```
SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('YourLoginName', 'PasswordLastSetTime');
```

Comment: Appreciate the time Joe, thanks; it worked fine. Heads up for those using windows integrated authentication, it will return NULL because login_name must be the name of a SQL Server login.

Answer (score -4):

select name, create_date from sys.sql_logins