# Find accounts with passwords that are not complex

Tags: sql-server-2014, security, password

I can see all the SQL Login passwords that enforce the password policy with this command

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE is_policy_checked = 1
```

However, it seems that when the enforce password policy is checked, it requires the next password change to enforce the policy and doesn't mean that current password does:

[This MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017) states

> Password complexity policies are designed to deter brute force attacks
>   by increasing the number of possible passwords. When password
>   complexity policy is enforced, new passwords must meet the following
>   guidelines:

I can verify the above as follows

Create login with weak password:

```
CREATE LOGIN [TestLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'weak', CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

Enforce the policy

```
ALTER LOGIN [TestLogin] WITH CHECK_POLICY=ON
```

at this point, the following query returns 1

```
SELECT is_policy_checked FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'TestLogin'
```

So is there anyway I can check which SQL accounts have a weak password? My guess is "no" as I would have thought this was a bit of a security vulnerability and the only way would be to change all the passwords when the policy has been set to check.

Comment: Correct, the answer is no because SQL Server only stores the salted login password hash rather than the password itself.

Comment: Also see https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/97898/1186 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/99262/1186

Comment: Dan is right - but another related approach is dbatools' [Test-DbaLoginPassword](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Test-DbaLoginPassword) which checks for nulls and username=password and also accepts a CSV for brute forcing other known values.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that will help 
PWDCOMPARE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdcompare-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Some example:
https://dzone.com/articles/use-pwdcompare-to-find-sql-logins-with-weak-passwo

Credits @SQLRockstar [link](https://stackexchange.com/users/23540/sqlrockstar)

First, let's build a list of weak passwords and save it to file:

```
$pwdList = Get-Content .\password_list.txt
```

Build a query and execute against SQL Server:

```
$SQLText = "SELECT name FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE PWDCOMPARE('$password', password_hash) = 1;"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQLText -ServerInstance $SQLServer
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will help with this question since the existing passwords are not known.

Comment: @DanGuzman same in the example from DZONE. They built the list of weak passwords and just compare it with existing passwords in the system.
Unless i am missing something. Can you please elaborate why the example is not good for this case?

Comment: Another feature I did not know about.  This can be used to find weak passwords if they are common.  Is it an oxymoron to have a weak uncommon password?

Comment: @MikeyBronowski, the question asks "check which SQL accounts have a weak password", meaning that they do not meet the complexity rules if `CHECK_POLICY=ON` were turned enforced. If you have a solution to check existing login passwords, add the code to your answer as I did not see it in the links. Also, when posting links in answers, one should include the relevant code snippet or excerpt in case the urn changes or content removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any enforcement responsibility or ability;

After you have modified enfource password policy in SQL.  You make a mandate that passwords need to be updated by a specific time/date and you can validate that has occured with

```
SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('YourLoginName', 'PasswordLastSetTime');
```

[Code source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8721/21924)

In general, all passwords should be changed regularly so it should be relatively easy to defend this policy change.

Automatic expiring passwords can be problematic for application access, so this may or may not be a viable solution in your environment.  But manually password changes should not pose a problem.

Comment: These days some may [disagree with forcing password](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~reiter/papers/2010/CCS.pdf) changes, though.